# Arduino delay is not precise

Tags: c++, arduino, delay

I'm new to Arduino, I'm building a simple sensor circuit using a DHT22 and a SparkFun ESP8266 Thing Dev module which is programmable with Arduino.

In my loop code I want my device to wait 5min so I placed at the end `delay(300000)`. The problem is that when I look into my database the timestamp when the data is collected by the sensor, sometimes it wait 2 minutes, sometimes 1 etc.

Furthermore, I have a logical check (if else) that should prevent my device to transmit data when the difference of temperature or humidity is less than **1**. But my device seems not to care about it.

I'm sure there should be something wrong with my code but this is the first time I try to use C++ and Arduino so I wasn't able to figure out what just yet. Any help?

This is my code:

```
#include <DHT.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <DNSServer.h>            
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>     
#include <WiFiManager.h>          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager WiFi Configuration Magic

#define DHTPIN 4
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);

// here I declare the variable of humidity and temperature. 
// every time it loops, it should get data from the sensor into 
// temp1 and hum1, then check it against temp and hum if there 
// are any changes in the values 
float temp;
float hum;
float temp1;
float hum1;

int red_light_pin = 16;
int green_light_pin = 12;
int blue_light_pin = 13;

// Server, file, and port
const char hostname[] = "laundryireland.tk";
const String uri = "/write_data?";
const String arguments[3] = {"serial=","&temp=","&hum="};
const int port = 80;

String serialNumber;

WiFiClient client;


void RGB_color(int red_light_value, int green_light_value, int blue_light_value)
 {
  analogWrite(red_light_pin, red_light_value);
  analogWrite(green_light_pin, green_light_value);
  analogWrite(blue_light_pin, blue_light_value);
}

void setup() {

  pinMode(red_light_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green_light_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue_light_pin,OUTPUT);
  RGB_color(0,0,255);

  WiFi.persistent(false);
  WiFiManager wifiManager;

  //Initialize Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  delay(100);

  //Connect to WiFi
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  wifiManager.autoConnect();
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {

    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }


  //Show that we are connected
  Serial.println("Connected!");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  serialNumber = WiFi.macAddress();

}

void loop() {
  delay(2000);
  temp1 = dht.readTemperature();
  hum1 = dht.readHumidity();
  while (temp1 == NULL || hum1 == NULL){
      RGB_color(255,0,0);
      delay(5000);
      temp1 = dht.readTemperature();
      hum1 = dht.readHumidity();
    }

// THIS IS MY IF STATEMENT TO CHECK FOR
// CHANGES IN TEMP OR HUM

  if (temp > temp1+1 || temp < temp1-1 || hum > hum1+1 || hum < hum1-1){
    temp = temp1;
    hum = hum1;

    RGB_color(0,255,0);
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.println(temp);
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.println(hum);

    Serial.println("Testing flask ");
    if ( client.connect(hostname,port) == 0 ) {
      Serial.println("Flask Test Failed!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Flask Test Success!");
      client.print("GET " + uri + arguments[0] + serialNumber +
                    arguments[1] + temp +
                    arguments[2] + hum +
                    " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                    "Host: " + hostname + "\r\n" +
                    "Connection: close\r\n" +
                    "\r\n");
      delay(500);

      while (client.available()){
        String ln = client.readStringUntil('\r');
        Serial.print(ln);
      }
    }

    client.stop();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Connection closed");

  } else {
    Serial.println("temp or hum not changed");
    RGB_color(255,255,0);
  }

// THIS SHOULD WAIT 5min BEFORE NEXT CHECK

  delay(300000);
}
```

This is how my database looks like:

[image: database]

---

**Solution**

Has pointed out by the commenters and well described in the accepted answer, the use of mills() instead of delay() solve the issue with "fake" delay time.

Furthermore, the problem of the transmission of data even when the difference between the previous update and the current one was less than 1; was just a logic problem with my if-else statement. I solved with this code:

```
 int deltaT = abs(temp-temp1);
    int deltaH = abs(hum-hum1);

    if (deltaT >= 1 || deltaH >= 1){
    // code here
```

Comment: The logic looks ok to me. I made a [mcve] to test: https://ideone.com/ptsRTH. Are you sure you have successfully uploaded the modified code to the Arduino?

Comment: It is not usually recommended you delay for such a long time period. This blocks the device from doing other things (though not completely). You should consider using timestamps instead with the [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function.

Comment: Also, `readTemperature` and `readHumidity` return `NAN` and not `NULL`.

Comment: `int` is 16 bits on the Arduino. `delay` probably takes an `int` parameter. 300000 is too big for 16 bits, so it probably wraps around.

Comment: I'm going to try using mills() and I'll let you know. Any advices regarding the other error: that the sensor will transmit to the database the humidity and temp values even if they are not more or less 1 degree/percent from the previous one?

Comment: A more accurate method may be to use a 1ms ISR.  The ISR will increment a counter.  When the counter reaches the desired time, read the sensors.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews can you make an example, what is 1ms ISR?

Comment: An ISR is an **I**nterrupt **S**ervice **R**outine.  Most microcontollers have timers.  More advance controllers have timers that can be set to cause an interrupt when the timer reaches a value (such as counting down to zero).  The timer interrupt register should have a slot where you can store an address for the timer interrupt to call / execute.  Some controllers may place this interrupt address in an "interrupt controller".  So, every time the timer interrupts, it will call your function.

Comment: A 1ms ISR is an ISR that is executed every millisecond.  Commonly, a timer is set to fire (interrupt) at 1ms intervals and execute a function.  In many embedded systems, this is used to generate clock ticks which can then be used by the operating system to do things like switch tasks and wake up tasks from sleeping.  On my project, the 1ms timer is used to read data from the hardware (such as ADC controllers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop function will be called again 300000msec AFTER the loop has finished.
So the time to the next recording is all the processing time of
* 2000 at the beginning
* the times for the functions dht.readTemperature() and dht.readHumidity();
* the time for sending bytes to the Serial output
* the time for client.connect and the network transfer time...
* and the 300000 at the end

A better approach is to get the current millis() from the system to check for 300000 msecs since the last reading.
Then calculate the next time for measurement and then do your processing

You can use a static variable for this to keep code together:

```
void loop() {
  static unsigned long next = 0;
  unsigned long now = millis();

  if (now > next) {
    … do processing
    next = now + 300000;
  } // if
} // loop()
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, but are you sure next should be declared and assigned inside the loop: `static unsigned long next = 0;` ? Won't this reset next to 0 at every loop making the `if` statement always `true`?

Comment: @FabioMagarelli `static` variables are only initialized once. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Comment: Thank you all, I have updated my code also to solve the issue of the transmission of data even when the difference of temp/hum was less than 1 degree